# $_SERVER VARS are empty

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.3.12 on a Windows system , i am trying to use some of the `$_SERVER` variables, but the following `$_SERVER` variables are empty for me

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

i have set `ServerName` in the config file, but `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT` are both empty and i have no idea why that is, how can i set those variables and prevent them from being empty?

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_SERVER);`?

Comment: what webserver you are using?

Comment: >Windows - not surprised :D What webserver are you using? Paste webserver`s config please.

Comment: PHP shouldn't even allowed to work on Windows... ! Post your ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure its IIS and have seen this happening before for REQUEST_URI try using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['argv'][0];
```